# Feature engineering while using neural networks

Tags: neural-network, feature-engineering

When doing Data Science, we concentrate on feature engineering first - check on correlations, imputations, tranformations etc.

Do we have to follow the same steps while feeding the inputs to a neural net? Or what should be the steps taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about tabular data (not images, video, sounds etc) then yes. All of preparations you mentioned are applicable to Artificial neural networks.

For instance, data normalization is very important since neurons activations are calculated applying some activation function on a weighted sum(linear combination) of it's inputs. A value of 0.01 and a value of 10000000 in a weighted sum will always have a large value if the weights are at the same scale. Theoretically the network could learn how to deal with such discrepancies on the input values but in a practical sense normalization can make learning faster.

There is a classical paper on efficient backprop, with many tips and tricks, by [Yann LeCun](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning data and bringing it into a proper format is very often necessary but I would call this step *data preparation* rather than *feature engineering*.

It may totally make sense to apply normalization techniques as Felipe Cruz already explained.
However, neural networks basically can approximate any function (see [this post](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html)) and thus this is also not really necessary.
It may still help especially in terms of training time, though.

A strength of neural networks comes from them learning the relevant features themselves.
You might develop a feature based on the combination of two or more properties of your input but a neural net with proper architecture would also be able to "come up" with this feature on its own if it sees enough samples for this during training.

I will go with the example of text here but analogous steps could basically be taken for any kind of input.
Lets suppose we're training a sentiment classifier for tweets.
The data could be cleaned by applying for example a spelling correction algorithm. Another preparation step then would be the vectorization of the input. We could tokenize the tweets and based on a vocabulary transform each word into a [one-hot vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot).
As for feature engineering, one important feature might be negation, i.e. the difference between "happy" and "not happy". It would take great effort to "manually" solve this problem as there are many ways to express negation (and then there's also irony...).
Suppose now we use a recurrent neural network that reads in the tweets word by word to predict the class in the end.
In the optimal case the network would learn this feature (and others) itself based on examples in the training data where negation influences the outcome.
I.e. in a simple case if there was a negating word like *not* in the sequence before reading the word *happy* the output is altered accordingly.

Then again, applying some domain knowledge to extract features could help the model to identify important patterns more easily and thus speed up learning (if the features you develop are really relevant and sufficiently represented in your training data).
But rather than focusing on feature engineering, it is the architecture of your net that you normally focus on to make the net learn the features itself.
In the end you only will know what works best by trying it out.